# AttributeError: 'IntVar' object has no attribute 'state'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to read the status of a **Checkbox** form Tkinter lib.
I tried two methods get() and state() but non of them returned the proper data, below is the code.
when you press the **Start** button then the program should read data from checkbox and do the process.

```
import tkinter as tk

def start():

    res = rs.state()
#   res = rs.get()
    print("the value of checkbox is: ", res)

win = tk.Tk()
# global rs
rs = tk.IntVar()
picheck = tk.Checkbutton(win, text="PI chart", variable=rs)

button = tk.Button(win, text="Start", command=start, pady=15, padx=25, bg='green', fg='white', font=35)

picheck.pack()
button.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

then I thought maybe it relates to calling the data from function so I made it global but did not work. At this point, the get() function only returns ZERO and the state() gives me the below error.

> AttributeError: 'IntVar' object has no attribute 'state'

Comment: `Checkbutton` needs the options `onvalue` and `offvalue`. [See](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_checkbutton.htm)

Comment: `get` [would seem to be](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.IntVar-class.html) the correct method; if it returns nothing, it might be because nothing was set.

Comment: `rs.get()` should return what you need: 0 for not checked, 1 for checked.